# Error when installing Pandas and Numpy with pip

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.11

Problem when installing pandas and numpy packages with red errors

Hello, sorry, I had a problem. Thank you for your answer
When I want Pandas in Python
3.11.3 When I install it, it gives me an error and I can't install it. It is exactly the same in numpy installation.
(This happens with the pip command, version 23.1.2)[This is the picture of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuJOA.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It seems you have a very slow connection. `pandas` is a large file and pip has a timeout implemented. Try increasing the timeout with `pip --timeout=1000 install pandas`